# Scons logging stdout/stderr

Tags: logging, scons

I am a beginner in SCons and I am just trying to logging all the information from stdout and stderr.

A short question: how can I write all the stdout/stderr output to a file?

Answer (score 3):

`scons 1>std.out 2>std.err`

Comment: This will work great if the OP is using some variant of Unix. Windows, on the other hand is a different story :)

Comment: `C:\Python27\Scripts>scons.bat 1>s 2>e
C:\Python27\Scripts>type e
scons: *** No SConstruct file found.
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons2.2.0\SCons\Script\Main.py", line 905, in _main`

Comment: Ok, sorry, I take that back. I recognized that as Unix, but didnt know that it worked on Windows too.